# How will I load wsdl in soap UI with xsd extensions?

Tags: wsdl, soapui

I have a wsdl with xsd extensions. If I load the wsdl in soap UI, I am not able to view my extensions. Is it possible to load a wsdl with its xsd extensions?

Thanks,
Priya.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not exactly sure what you're meaning with xsd extensions. When loading the WSDL from a remote system, i.e. the actual webservice, then the XSD should be loaded automatically. If you're loading the WSDL from a local file just make sure that you put the .xsd file in the correct directory as referenced in the WSDL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and time. I wanted to know how do I load the sub-objects. Say like, I have base objects in WSDL and its sub-object placed in the XSD as extensions. When I load that in SoapUI, I get to see only base objects, but when I create stub using axis or cxf, I get all the objects.

Comment: This sounds strange indeed. Sorry, I have no idea. HAve you tried contacting the Eviware support for soapUI at support@eviware.com? They usually provide helpful answers very quickly.

Comment: I could see open question on the same .http://markmail.org/message/w5lz26pxfjhvi36s?q=xsd+extension+testing+in+SOAPUI&page=1&refer=s2l3wl2eodc2wvvu#query:xsd%20extension%20testing%20in%20SOAPUI+page:1+mid:hjdderju4vbvesre+state:results and refer 
http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=4568&start=0
on the same.

Comment: Make sure that the extensions are accessible from where you are running SoapUI. Otherwise you may need to copy the WSDL and XSDs locally, and re-consume from there, possibly by hacking the paths.